# Как оформить ссылки

Tags: сноски

Исходный текст:
В основном они построены по схемам того времени (Иванов, Петров)*.
* означает сноску на подстрочную ссылку: * Сидоров.
То есть в источнике Сидоров указаны источники Иванов, Петров.
Есть необходимость переделать все ссылки на внутритекстовые, то есть они все должны быть в скобках в тексте.
Как это сделать?
Можно ли так:
В основном они построены по схемам того времени (Сидоров: Иванов, Петров).

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть **реальный** текст — только тогда, как мне кажется, можно сказать что-то конкретное.

Comment: В приведенном тексте просто убраны "лишние" слова и упрощены фамилии.

Comment: Радик, отредактируй вопрос. Мне, как и Римме, непонятно вообще, об чём речь.