# Оформление внутритекстовых ссылок

Tags: запрос-ссылок

Если описание источника указано в списке лит-ры, допустимо ли внутритекстовую ссылку дать в след. виде: (Иванов, 1980, С. 5)?
То есть можно ли между фамилией, датой и страницей ставить запятые?

Comment: Разве не спрашивали это: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445627/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: Нет, это другой вопрос.

Comment: Рад, я Вам ответила в дополнении — уже после "комментов". (Если описание источника указано в списке лит-ры, допустимо ли внутритекстовую ссылку дать в след. виде: (Иванов, 1980, с. 5), то есть везде запятые?) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445660/Употребление-различных-скобок/445669#445669

Comment: Извините, смотрел ответ в комментах. Теперь всё понятно. Этот вопрос ликвидировать или оставить?